# Quickbooks Sales Receipt add error

Tags: quickbooks

> There was an error when saving a SalesReceipt. QuickBooks error
>   message: Transaction amount must be positive.

When I submit this xml to my quickbooks webconnector it throws me the above error. What is the transaction amount and where in the xml does it go?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
 <SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="1">
  <SalesReceiptAdd>
 <CustomerRef>
   <FullName>Daily Sales Summary</FullName> 
   </CustomerRef>
 <TemplateRef>
 <FullName>Custom Sales Receipt</FullName> 
 </TemplateRef>
 <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
 <ItemRef>
 <FullName>Food</FullName> 
 </ItemRef>
  <Desc>Total Food Sales</Desc> 
  <Amount>50.00</Amount> 
 </SalesReceiptLineAdd>
  </SalesReceiptAdd>
   </SalesReceiptAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score -1):

Need item for SalesReceiptLineAdd

Something like that:

```
<SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="2"><SalesReceiptAdd><CustomerRef><FullName>Dang Dinh*</FullName></CustomerRef><TxnDate>2013-11-15</TxnDate><CheckNumber/><PaymentMethodRef><FullName>Check</FullName></PaymentMethodRef><Memo>Test</Memo><IsToBePrinted>False</IsToBePrinted<SalesReceiptLineAdd><ItemRef><FullName>Sales</FullName></ItemRef><Desc>Test</Desc><Quantity>1</Quantity><Rate>1</Rate></SalesReceiptLineAdd></SalesReceiptAdd></SalesReceiptAddRq>
```